# i can find the symbol in libleveldb.a,but when i create the shared library,failed to find the same symbol.what's wrong?

Tags: c++

I've created a leveldb's java client to fit YCSB and need to use JNI. So I built the shared library based on `libleveldb.a` but it generate some error.

test.cpp:

```
#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        leveldb::DB* db;
        leveldb::Options options;
        options.create_if_missing = true;
        leveldb::Status status = 
        leveldb::DB::Open(options,"/tmp/testdb", &db);
        assert(status.ok());
```

Makefile:

```
g++ test.cpp -fPIC -shared -o libTest.so
```

i expect i can find the `_ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev` symbol in .so file.
but the symbol output is:

```
$ daniel@daniel-MS-7A74:~/leveldb/test_zdn$ readelf -s libTest.so|grep leveldb7Options
10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
63: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev

$ daniel@daniel-MS-7A74:~/leveldb/test_zdn$ readelf -s test.o|grep leveldb7Options
1882: 0000000000037dc4   183 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
2628: 0000000000037dc4   183 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC2Ev
```

the shndx column is UNDEFINED in libTest.so

Comment: Curious why you think this is a failure to find the symbol. It's listed right there. The question is what "NOTYPE" in the shndx column signifies.

Comment: and also,you can find the _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev symbol in libleveldb.a,but seems that the link process doesn't find the symbol.

Comment: what does `ldd libTest.so` gives?

Comment: daniel@daniel-MS-7A74:~/leveldb/test_zdn$ ldd libTest.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe8e1fe000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff44531e000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff445106000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff444d15000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff444977000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff4458ab000)

Comment: the reason i think it's wrong is that,jni call  get output java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, and i googled ,lead to UND symbol.so  do you mean UND symbol in *.so is alright?

Answer (score 0):

> i misunderstand the link process,that's because static library has undefined symbol is alright.
>   static library is archive of object file,and obj is okay to have und symbol.
>   but,you have to add the dependency library when you use the static library(same with dynamic library).
>
> > https://blog.csdn.net/tom06/article/details/80309864